# How to create an AutoNumber field value in Access?

Tags: ms-access, autonumber

I'm trying the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    RecordNo autonumber, --error here!
    PersonId varchar(50),
    ...
)
```

But, there is an error.
How can I build the correct query in Access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [SQL Auto Increment a Field](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_autoincrement.asp):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

> The MS Access uses the `AUTOINCREMENT`
>   keyword to perform an auto-increment
>   feature.
>
> By default, the starting value for
>   `AUTOINCREMENT` is 1, and it will
>   increment by 1 for each new record.
>
> To specify that the "`P_Id`" column
>   should start at value 10 and increment
>   by 5, change the autoincrement to
>   `AUTOINCREMENT(10,5)`.

Synonyms for `AUTOINCREMENT` include `COUNTER` and `IDENTITY`. Using `IDENTITY` the makes a lot of sense because it matched the `@IDENTITY` variable which returns the last used autonumber value.

Answer (score 3):

The order might be important

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
( pkObject AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
```

If I try `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as suggested, it gets upset (MSAccess 2010).

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

1. Open table in design view
2. Make a field named "ID" or whatever the field will be that will have the Auto Increment
3. Put "AutoNumber" under DataType

Method 2:

1. Make a new table
2. Close the table and save it
3. When it asks if you want a primary key click ok
4. Open the table in Design View
5. Edit the new field to whatever name you like

Answer (score 1):

When using ancient DAO 3.60 and Jet 4.0 with Access 2003 files, Eugene Yokota'a syntax did not work. I found that COUNTER keyword will do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(id COUNTER, Name Text (30))
```

Thanks to this post:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?234335