# How to insert values into an Access table's AutoNumber field?

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert, autonumber

I'm working on a project using jsp and Microsoft Access.

There are three tables in which a same field is used as `Receipt_No`.
This can get from `Recp` table, which has a only one field: `Receipt_No (AutoNumber, Primary Key)`.

Now my question is, how can I insert in this AutoNumber field with every generation of receipt?.

Comment: It is generated automatic, thats why its called AUTOnumber.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Auto Number Field in access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072932/how-to-create-auto-number-field-in-access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING** This is ghetto. (But then again I'm thinking a table with ONLY an autonumber field is kinda ghetto too, so oh well.)

`INSERT INTO yourTable (your_autonumber_field) SELECT max(your_autonumber_field) + 1 FROM yourTable`

Not elegant, but it works.  That will create a new record in your Receipt table.  It defeats the whole purpose of having an autonumber field but I don't see another way to use SQL to create a record in a table with only an autonumber field.  You can then retrieve the newly created receipt ID with a `SELECT max(your_autonumber_field) FROM yourTable` for use in your FK fields in the other tables.

Comment: Just accept this answer - mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer

Answer (score 1):

The autonumber field has the property that it gets numbered accordingly as the records are entered into the table. its smthng like autoincrement